# Javascript to image fallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am working on a web widget that can be embedded on 3rd party websites.

Since a lot of content management systems do not allow users to post/execute scripts, I want my widget to show an image instead of JS-generated content if such situation occurs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){var s = document.createElement('script');s.src = '//example.com/file.js';s.async = "async";document.body.appendChild(s);}());
</script>
<img src="//example.com/image.svg?param1=value1" src="" id="my_fallback">
```

For now I am using the code above. Is there any way to show the image only if the script did not load? The goal is to reduce transfer usage and provide better user experience.

The first line of my widget script is removing `#my_fallback`, but it is not fast enough - sometimes I can see the image for a second before the actual widget content replaces it.

The only thing I came up with is to delay creation of the image by including something like sleep() in the beginning of my image generator.

**EDIT**

No, `<noscript>` won't work here. I do not want to fallback if user has disabled javascript. I want to fallback when a script has not loaded - for any reason, especially if some security mechanism cut off the `<script>` section.

Answer (score 4):

Use html tag Noscript

```
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript! or a image here</noscript>
```

Remember

In HTML 4.01, the  tag can only be used inside the  element.

In HTML5, the  tag can be used both inside  and .

Edit : - 
add one html tag

```
<span class="noscript">script is loading.....or put image</span>
```

inside your script tag

now in your scripts which has to be load add one code like
add this line at the end

```
$('.noscript').hide();
```

This is the other way which you can handle the same!

Comment: Please, read my question carefully. I do not want to fallback if user has disabled javascript. I want to fallback when a script has not loaded - for any reason, especially if some security mechanism cut off the `<script>` section

Comment: Why don't you read the question you're answering? I wrote that I am doing exactly that and I am looking for something better... Edit: Putting it inside `<script>` won't give me anything, because it can be cut off.

Comment: @dev9 sorry! no idea man! I can't read your question my eyes are blinking

Comment: @dev9 Welcome to SO family. first thing you need to know that its not a forum or not a blog. when someone tries to help you You should appreciate their answer. you should not behave like that *Why don't you read the question you're answering?* if he could not understand ur question then u should try to describe it well.

Answer (score 0):

One quick fix is to create a global variable from that script, visible to the window object.Also the image must be hidden. Then, on a main.js script check for that variable. If it exists then run your widget code from there. If it doesnt exist then fadeIn the fallback image.

Heres a **[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9P1fH4?p=preview)**

The default img is an image 272x178 size and the widget image is an image 300x400 size.

To simulate the action when the script is unavailable, just name the variable `myWidgetIsEnabled` with a different name so the condition fails.
Here is some code:

```
// Code goes here
var widget = (function(){
 window.myWidgetIsEnabled = true;
  return {
    init: function(){
    var s = document.createElement('script');s.src = 'file.js';s.async = "async";
    document.body.appendChild(s);}
 }
}());

$(document).ready(function(){
 if(window.myWidgetIsEnabled){
  widget.init();
  }else{
  console.log('not enabled, the default behavior');
  $('.fallback').fadeIn();
 }
})
```

Comment: The problem is I do not know if any of my JS code is going to be executed.